# Solve the simultaneous equations for real numbers $x$ and $y$: $ \sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x-a} = 3 $ and $ x+y=5 $

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

> > Question: Let $a$ be a real number. Solve the simultaneous equations for real numbers $x$ and $y$:
> >
> > $$ \sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x-a} = 3 $$
> >
> > $$ x+y=5 $$

---

My attempt:

Consider the first equation:

$$ \sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x-a} = 3 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x-a})^2 = 3^2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x+a+x-a + 2\sqrt{x^2-a^2} = 9 $$

$$\Leftrightarrow  2\sqrt {x^2-a^2} = 9 - 2x $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  4(x^2-a^2) = 81 - 36x + 4x^2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 4x^2 - 4a^2 = 81-36x + 4x^2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 36x = 4a^2 + 81  $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{1}{36} \left(4a^2+81\right) $$

Subbing this into the second equation

$$ x+y = 5 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{36} \left(4a^2+81\right) + y = 5$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 4a^2 + 81 + 36y = 180 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow 36y = 99 - 4a^2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow y = \frac{11}{4} -\frac{a^2}{9} $$

What should I do now?

Comment: Something seems off...if $a$ is large then $x+a>9$ so your first relation can't hold.  Your solution is only valid for $a$ in some range.  Keep in mind:  when you square an equation you sometimes pick up unwanted solutions.

Comment: The first equation has no solution in the reals if $a > 9/2$.

Comment: You only need to find the interval where $x+a \ge 0$ and $x-a \ge 0$, because in this interval the $\sqrt{x+a}$ and $\sqrt{x-a}$ are defined. **HINT**: Put the value of $x$ that you calculate, substitute on each square root and solve the inequation.

Comment: @BrianTung how did you get a>9/2

Comment: @LuisVictoria how do I set up the inequation?

Comment: @dydxx: What happens if $a > 9/2$?  Then $x$ must be how much in order to avoid a negative argument of the second square root?  Then $x+a$ must be how much?

Comment: @dydxx in your solution of $x$ you get $x = \frac{1}{36} \left(4a^2+81\right)$ if we want that $x+a \ge 0$ we put the value of $x$; you get $$\frac{1}{36} \left(4a^2+81\right)+a \ge 0$$ after doing algebra you get $4a^2+36a+81 \ge 0$ and you solve this as a regular second-order equation and you get $a \ge -\frac{9}{2}$ and do the same for the oder inequation, $x-a \ge 0$.

Comment: @LuisVictoria and we get $a \geq \frac{9}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, but having  both inequation together we have that $\forall a \ge \frac{9}{2}$ the square roots are defined in $\mathbb R$. But if $a \gt \gt x$, $a$ its bigger than $x$, we have that $x-a \approx -a \lt 0$ this is a contradiction so the inequalities are wrong or the value of $x$ its wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We see that
$$x = 5-y$$
$$\implies \sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x-a} = 3$$
$$\implies \sqrt{5-y+a} + \sqrt{5-y-a} = 3$$
$$\implies (\sqrt{5-y+a} + \sqrt{5-y-a})^2 = 10 + 2\sqrt{5-y+a}\sqrt{5-y-a} - 2y = 9$$
$$\implies 10 + \sqrt{(5-y+a)(5-y-a)} - 2y = 9$$
$$\implies 10 + \sqrt{(y-5)^2-a^2} - 2y = 9$$
$$\implies 2\sqrt{(y-5)^2-a^2} = 2y - 1$$
$$\implies (2\sqrt{(y-5)^2-a^2})^2 = 4((y-5)^2 - a^2) = (2y-1)^2 = 4y^2-4y+1$$
$$\implies  100-4a^2-40y+4y^2 = 4y^2-4y+1$$
$$\implies 100 - 4a^2 - 36y - 1 = 0$$
$$\implies 99 - 4a^2 - 36y = 0$$
$$\implies -36y = -99 + 4a^2 \implies y = \frac{99}{36} - \frac{4}{36}a^2$$
$$\implies y = \frac{11}{4} - \frac{1}{9}a^2.$$
$$\implies x = 5-y = 5-\frac{11}{4}+\frac{1}{9}a^2 = \frac{9}{4}+ \frac{1}{9}a^2.$$

Comment: How does this differ from the solution which appears in the question?

Comment: but if you insert your solution in the first equation we get $$\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3}a-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}=3$$

Comment: how would you simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed without loss of generality that $a\ge 0$.

Let $x = a(\sec^2{\theta}+\tan^2{\theta})$

This is valid since $x \ge a$ and the least value of $\sec^2{\theta}+\tan^2{\theta}$ is $1$

Now, consider the interval $0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{2}$

Then the first equation simplifies to

$$\sec{\theta}+\tan{\theta} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2a}}$$

This can be tediously bashed using the Weierstrass Substitution $t = \tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$

Then use that to obtain the corresponding $x$ value, and then $y$.

Similar arguments hold for the remaining three quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

Let us set that $\alpha = \sqrt{x+a}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{x-a}$. Thence we obtain $\alpha + \beta = 3$ and $\alpha^{2} - \beta^{2} = 2a$, which means that
\begin{align*}
\alpha^{2} - \beta^{2} = (\alpha+\beta)(\alpha-\beta) = 3(\alpha-\beta) = 2a \Leftrightarrow \alpha - \beta = \frac{2a}{3}
\end{align*}
From this system of equations, we obtain the following solution $\displaystyle(\alpha,\beta) = \left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{a}{3},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{a}{3}\right)$. Hence:

\begin{align*}
\alpha = \sqrt{x+a} & = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{a}{3} \Leftrightarrow x + a = \left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{a}{3}\right)^{2}\Leftrightarrow x = \left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{a}{3}\right)^{2} - a
\end{align*}

Whenever $x\geq-a$ and $\displaystyle a\geq-\frac{9}{2}$. Analogously, we obtain:

\begin{align*}
\beta = \sqrt{x-a} = \frac{3}{2}-\frac{a}{3} \Leftrightarrow x -a = \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{a}{3}\right)^{2} \Leftrightarrow x = \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{a}{3}\right)^{2} + a
\end{align*}

Whenever $x\geq a$ and $\displaystyle a\leq\frac{9}{2}$. Finally, you are able to find the solution set for $x\geq|a|$ and $|a| \leq 4.5$ if you are looking for real solutions. Hope this helps.